# chronojs gives wrong start date when string has something before the start date

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp

I am using `chronojs`:

https://github.com/wanasit/chrono

The following gives the wrong start date. It gives start date as 03 instead of 17.

```
let parsed = chrono.parse('Appointments from 17 August 2013 to 19 August 2013')[0]

console.log(parsed.start.date()) // prints: Sat Aug 03 2013 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
console.log(parsed.end.date()) // prints: Mon Aug 19 2013 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Even if the string is `' 17 August 2013 to 19 August 2013'`
it gives the wrong result for start date. NOTE the space before  `17`

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?